# Modifying a class buried deep in a complex object - c#

Tags: c#, derived-class

I have a class I wish to modify the property names of.

However this class is buried about 6 classes deep in a much much larger class(also all custom classes).

My problem is I cant touch any of the existing classes.

The only solution I can think of is to derive from the root class, stick it in a new namespace, then create new classes at each stage inbetween the root class and the class I wanted to modify.

Hopefully this makes sense what Im trying to explain.

Is the above method the only way?

Comment: Is it absolutely essential that you must modify the property names? You can't modify the code that "produces" these properties, but can you modify the code that "consumes" them? A much better solution would be to wrap some kind of adapter object around the one whose property names you want to change.

Comment: Is the class you want to change a `partial` class?

Comment: @Mike how would that make any difference? partial is a compiler keyword

Comment: @IanNorton - if it's a `partial` class the OP could extend the class with their own properties (just as they are suggesting already) but not have to inherit from it. Therefore, they could build another `partial`, do what they need with the new properties, and not go through the process of rebuilding the heirarchy.

Comment: @Mike yes it is. I will be doing a bit of research whilst I eat my lunch :)

Comment: I have added an answer to give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've stated the class you want to extend is a `partial` class I'm going to recommend that you extend it as such as well. Now you can easily add the new properties, as you've already suggested, and extend the class by **adding a class in the same namespace with the same name**.

In the example below, both classes are named `A` and both classes are in the same `namespace` - those are the two keys to building `partial` classes.

```
public partial class A
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public partial class A
{
    public string PropertyC
    {
        get
        {
            var val = this.PropertyA;
            // some more functionality maybe...
            return val;
        }
        set
        {
            // some more functionality maybe...
            this.PropertyA = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to shoot me down here, but out of interest why is a partial class better in this situation? It will still compile into a single class. Additionally by not marking the old attributes obsolete, other users now get the confusing option of two properties doing the same thing. If you were to mark the old attributes as obsolete you would have the edit the inital class, making a partial class less useful. Thanks

Comment: @JamesWood - I can fully understand where you're coming from here, but I think the OP is not in a situation where those types of design decisions are a concern. At this point it appears they just need to get some new functionality onto the class and it appears to be really isolated. Finally, the OP was specifically looking for a way to keep from having to rebuild the inheritance heirarchy and this was effectively the most straight foward way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create properties with the new names, but keep the old properties there with the [Obsolete] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as compromise you could create additional properties with the new names, then existing code uses the old properties. You could then additionally mark the old attributes as obsolete.

```
class Example
{
    int oldField;

    [Obsolete("This is obsolete")]
    public int OldField
    {
        get
        {
            return this.oldField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.oldField = value;
        }
    }

    public int NewField
    {
        get
        {
            return this.oldField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.oldField = value;
        }
    }
}
```